# Azure AD Authentication with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have an application which has both angular web part and spring rest backend. I want to integrate with Azure AD and have done with microsoft-adal-angular6 in angular and AADAuthenticationFilter in spring part. I need to first authenticate with Azure AD and then need to check whether that user exists in my local DB to which my application has connected. Is there any best practices for doing this two level authentication? Or rather how can I achieve this? Please anyone help.....

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In your security configuration you can then configure it, without writing it from scratch, you can start with: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-ldap

Comment: In my application I have used the below dependencies<dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
   <artifactId>azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Comment: So if you have a connection to your AD, then you just have to chain the calls in your securityConfig

Comment: With the help of microsoft-adal-angular6 module in angular I could authenticate Azure AD and able to get IDToken. With this IDToken I call the rest of the apis. There are some userspecific data in my database. So for every login I need to authenticate with my local DB also. But it should be done only once ( the local db checking for security reasons). For the rest of my api calls it should bypass the db checking.